# iPhone: What are the Advantages and Disadvantages of Developing with CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css

There are alternatives to developing for iPhone besides the native Objective-C API. In particular, there are CSS/Javascript based solutions such as the [iUi Framework](http://code.google.com/p/iui/).

Can you write successful iPhone apps with CSS/Javascript? Does Apple approve such apps? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using this approuch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One short comment: Apple does not need to approve apps written in CSS/JavaScript, as you host them on your server. They have nothing to do with the iPhone SDK and won't appear in the AppStore (unless you write a wrapper App in Objective-C).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) You can write successful apps with CSS/Javascript. The first generation of iPhone apps were all CSS/Javascript.

(2) Apple routinely approves such apps.

(3) The advantages are that you can leverage your existing knowledge of CSS/Javascript to write apps without having to learn a new language and a new API. The disadvantage is that such apps are not as fast, flexible and powerful as compiled apps. It is exactly the same situation as on a non-mobile platform. Webapps do not compare to apps written with the system specific API.

However, in some cases they can be almost as good. For example, if the main purpose of your app is to interact with a specific web site, then a CSS/Javascript app will probably perform just as well as a compiled one.

Comment: A checkmark would be appreciated if appropriate. It also makes people more willing to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

There's not really any question as to the "best way". There's just *a way*; that is, using UIKit and Obj-C, with OpenGL ES for games.

There are some other approaches, but they are generally, well, not so good. Developing applications for the iPhone using CSS/JS is a bit half-assed; but doesn't really require apple approval; seeing as how they are just web apps.

Comment: Erm, why aren't web applications real applications? With HTML5 the program is accessible offline, it even has access to a database for storing data. You can build a full application in JS. But to stay on topic, I think it's quite possible, but it just won't be as fast. However, as the application runs in Safari, Apple doesn't need to approve it.

Comment: Bookmarked just so I can come back tomorrow and downvote this answer. (I've ran out of votes for today.)

Comment: Williham, your edit is plain horrible. Why don't you try and write a question in Yakub's language (Hindi)? Go rot in a sewer or something please.

Comment: I'll just add that using CSS/JS will make sure that your application will also work on other devices such as Blackberry's or even on a desktop pc.